# $y$−intercept of a Parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you help with this question?

Which of the following is the $y$−intercept of a parabola represented by the equation $y=(x^2)−3x−4$?

$0$

$1$

$-4$

$-6$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate the parabola when $x = 0$.

Plugging in $0$ for x gives  us $$y=(0)^2−3(0)−4 \iff y = -4$$

Comment: I evaluated Answer is -4 Is it Correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. The y-intercept is $-4$, since it crosses the $y$ axis at the point $(0, -4)$.

Comment: I am bit confused in this question: ___________ of domain must have image in the range under the defined function?  Atleast one element, Each element, Not all elements OR Any number of elements?

Comment: **Each element** in the domain of a function must have an image in its range.

Comment: are you sure with each element? Because defined function must map every element of its domain to an element

Comment: Each element in the domain means "every" element in the domain...

Answer (score 0):

Consider $y=x^2+ 3x-4$, for $y$-intercept put $x=0$ to get $y=-4$